# Concentration inequality for $k$-dependent Bernoulli r.v.s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

Given $X_1,X_2, \cdots$ are iid $Ber(p)$, and we define 
$$Z_1 = X_1X_2\cdots X_k\\ Z_2 = X_2 X_3 \cdots X_{k+1}\\ \cdots$$
Is there a concentration inequality (like Hoeffding's inequality) for 
$$\mathbb{P}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i - \mathbb{E}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\Big]\geq t\bigg) \leq e^{(\cdots)}?$$

Comment: A clumsy bound can be obtained by simply taking union bound $$ \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}Z_i-\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}Z_i\right]\geq t\right)\leq\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}\mathbb{P}\Bigg(\sum_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\i\equiv r\text{ mod }{k}}}Z_i-\mathbb{E}\Bigg[\sum_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\i\equiv r\text{ mod }{k}}}Z_i\Bigg]\geq t/k\Bigg)$$ and applying Hoeffding's inequality to each term, which is possible becaue $(Z_{qk+r})_{q\geq 0}$ are i.i.d. $\text{Ber}(p^k)$ RVs.

Comment: My first guess would be to look at Janson's paper on partly dependent variables (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/rsa.20008). If the bound you extract from that is too weak, you might want to look at negative association on random variables.

Comment: Negatively associated random variables might be useful. See here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dwajc/notes/Negative%20Association.pdf

Comment: In fact, the sequence $Z_i$ is $k$-dependent - $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ is independent of $(Z_{n+k},\ldots)$ - and I believe the literature contains essentially matching concentration bounds for finitely dependent processes as for iid processes.

Comment: For instance, try searching in google scholar for papers citing this one: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077475030 as that was the earliest paper proving a CLT for finitely dependent random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 1.16 of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06871 applies to your situation. To summarize, the authors establish a concentration inequality for block factors of iid, of which your example is a special case. More precisely, a $k$-block factor of iid is a process $(Z_i)$ for which there exists a function $F\colon \mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R$ and an iid sequence $(X_i)$ such that $Z_i=F(X_i,X_{i+1},\ldots,X_{i+k-1})$. In your case, $F(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=x_1\cdots x_k$.